# What's the best way to update PHP files to live server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am accessing my remote server directory(/var/www) using the tool WINSCP. When I need to update a PHP file on the remote server, I work on a copy on my laptop (Windows 7), then I upload that copy to the corresponding directory at the remote server (by clicking right click on the file on the laptop directory, then I chose upload from the menu, then from the prompt I chose move and replace).

My question, during the transfer process, assume there is a user is using the system and he made a process was not done yet (let us say a process in mysql was working) and suddenly the PHP file is replaced with another one during the process. Will this make problem for my application? Is it healthy? Will it stop or a corruption will happen to database?

Shall I kick out all users before replacing PHP files at remote server? (that would be so hard option).

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad, opinion-based, and dependent upon your unique needs. Best practices and "what would you do?" kinds of questions don't fit here.

Comment: The file is only read once and loaded into memory. From there PHP operates on what is loaded into memory. I am pretty sure that if the file was being read when you go to upload it then your upload would wait until the file was freed. If PHP needs your file while it is being written to the disk then PHP would wait to load the file into memory.

Comment: It's quite small actually, if you consider this question to be about 1 php file only? see the answer by, for instnace, @ojovirtual. So this is neither very broad, nor an opinion: you can update a file when it is 'in use' like this.

Comment: Things get tricky when one parent file has several child includes which are included at different timespans of the parent script because the parent script relies on new variables set in the child scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP read the whole script before running it, so replacing the file will have no effect on this, you can keep doing it like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple PHP files and you are changing the API between them (add parameters to functions in your lib, for instance), you could run into trouble.

Same is if you use a database and you have to update your table definition.

As long as only a single PHP file changes, you are completely safe.